# Turning numbers in a file into integers with Python

Tags: python, string

So I have this text file that looks like this:

```
3
4
1 8 7 6 41
```

What I have to do is read the numbers from the file and work with them as integers in Python. How can I convert each line to a list that has each number as a separate item? For example numbers which are more than one digit such as 41 gets split into 4 and 1.

Comment: is each of the numbers on a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read a Python tutorial on working with files. I also recommend you learn how to use the `int` function.

```
number_file = open("numbers.txt")

for line in number_file:
    line_list = []
    for part in line.split():
        try:
            line_list.append(int(part))
        except:
            pass
    print(line_list)

number_file.close()
```

Comment: wont this still split 41 in too 4 and 1 in line list?

Comment: is that not what you wanted? i can edit it if you want

Comment: thanks for the help I just nedeed to split the line by whitespace just found it online thanks for your help though :)

Comment: if this helped please accept this or another answer as the answer to help other users with the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Update the file name and run the script.

```
number_list = dict()
counter = 0
with open("test_file.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:  
  for l in file:
    counter = counter + 1
    number_list[counter] = [ int(str_num) for str_num in l.split()]
print(number_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
final_list=[]
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for item in line.split():
            if len(item)==1:
                final_list.append(int(item.strip()))
            else:
                final_list.extend(list(map(lambda x:int(x),list(item))))
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[3, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6, 4, 1]
```